# Sudden change to have CORS bulkdocs couchDB error

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

CORS is enabled and development was going well but I have just moved to working with bulkdocs and after a bit of work I get a CORS error which seems to be something more to do with number of requests as project will be working fine but all of a sudden I get this CORS error in the console and I cannot connect anymore, even when code is on same domain just different subdomains.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sub.domain.com/couchdocs/_bulk_docs. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Could it be that I calling bulkdocs too often?

Apologies this is a little vague but issue is so odd.

UPDATE added some of the upload code from file input

```
ADD_FILE(state, files) {
  pouchdb
    .get(state.myclient)
    .then(function(doc) {
      console.log(files)
      console.log(state.notes)
      return pouchdb.bulkDocs([
        {
          _id: state.myclient,
          _rev: doc._rev,
          notes: state.notes,
          _attachments: {
            text: {
              data: files,
              content_type: files.type
            }
          }
        }
      ])
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      // handle response
      console.log(response)
      if (response.ok == true) {
        // not empty line
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
      if (err.status == 404) {
        // pouchdb.put({  })
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: What's the HTTP status code of of the response? Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error instead of a 200 OK success response? 4xx and 5xx errors won't have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, so that's why your browser will report a CORS message. But in those cases you don't really have a CORS problem to fixー of course the real problem you need to fix is whatever's causing the 4xx or 5xx error. So if you control the server sending the response, then you'd want to look at the server logs there to see what information the server is logging before the error

Comment: Thanks will do. I found it seems to be triggered as I started returning attachments I had added to pouchdb as well so I think it must be something related to that

Comment: I also wonder if I am making to many calls as I sync the data with changes and this includes attachments if I don’t include them bulkDocs will wipe them out and only update the doc stuff

Comment: I realised i needed to use bulkDocs to add attachments but as soon as I do now I trigger CORS

Comment: Request Entity Too Large 413

Comment: There's your answer.

Comment: Yes will add line I added to nginx. Thankfully I had git branches as the code was good server was bad

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/8064

Answer (score 1):

Had to add

client_max_body_size 20M;

to my nginx, was as simple as that